# Batch convert pdf files with pfdtk but with spaces in the name

Tags: batch-file, pdf, merge, pdftk

I am trying to merge large numbers of pdf files with similar numbers

eg "NR 01234567_1.pdf"
"NR 01234567_2.pdf"
etc
in a folder with thousands of similar pages of files that need to be merged per filename
eg "NR 01234567.pdf"

I have been succesful with this method with all files that had no spaces in the filename using the script below (thanks to some very helpful people on this forum) but it doens't work with spaces in the name.

Could anyone help me with this?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize (delete) "lastFile" and "fileList" variables
set "lastFile="
set "fileList="

rem Next line get the output of a "dir /B" command, that show file names *only*
rem "for /F" command execute the dir, get the output and divide each line in two "tokens" ("%%a" and "%%b")
rem with the first part before the "_" in "%%a" and the *rest* (including further "_") in "%%b"

for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *.*') do (

   rem If the base file name changed...
   if "%%a" neq "!lastFile!" (

      rem Process previous file list;
      rem this "if" is just to avoid process the empty list the first time
      if defined fileList (
         pdftk !fileList! output !lastFile!.pdf
      )

      rem Reinitialize the new list
      set "lastFile=%%a"
      set "fileList=%%a_%%b"

   ) else (

      rem Append this file to current list
      set "fileList=!fileList! %%a_%%b"

   )

)

rem Process the last list
pdftk !fileList! output !lastFile!.pdf
```

Comment: As a best practice you should always use "quotes" when using file names or file paths in a batch file. For the same exact reason you are using them with the IF comparisons and with the SET commands.

Comment: Jeroen Grommen, I have noticed that you have returned as logged into this site but have not responded to either of your officially provided answers. Please see What should I do when someone answers my question? to discover what options are open to you in this scenario, because a question without an accepted answer is not treated by this site as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
  set "fileList="%%a_%%b""

) else (

  rem Append this file to current list
  set "fileList=!fileList! "%%a_%%b""
```

AND

```
 pdftk !fileList! output "!lastFile!.pdf"
```

(both places)

[untried - I don't have `pdftk` (AFAIK)]

The idea is to build `filelist` as `"xy abcd" "xy defg"` - deliberately including the quotes = so that `pdftk` sees `"xy abcd" "xy defg"` as its list-of-files-to-combine and `"xy doom"` as the destination file (yes - I've taken liberties with the names. As "New Math" would describe it, ["it's the idea that counts"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIKGV2cTgqA))

Answer (score 0):

I think that there may be a simpler way of doing this task. It is my recollection that `pdftk.exe` has a `cat` option which will work with a wildcard/glob. So instead of creating a list of files, you could just use that option instead.

Here's an example, *(please, first change the location of `pdftk.exe` on line `3`)*, and run it with the directory holding your PDF files as the current directory:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "tkPDF=P:\ath\To\pdftk.exe"
Set "lastPreName="
For /F "EOL=_ Tokens=*" %%G In ('Dir "*_*.pdf" /B /A:-D /O:N 2^> NUL
 ^| "%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe" /I /R "^.[^_]*_[^_]*.pdf$"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=_" %%H In ("%%~nG") Do (
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If /I Not "!lastPreName!" == "%%~H" (
        Echo="%tkPDF%" "%%~H_*%%~xG" cat output "%%~H%%~xG")
    EndLocal
    Set "lastPreName=%%~H")
Pause
```

If you're satisfied with the output, which will presently only show the commands which would be run, remove `Echo=` from line `10`, and the optional `Pause` on line `13`

Comment: Perfect, this solves it ! Thank you so much!